# How can I resolve showing empty image in opencv?

Tags: c++, c, image, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I use opencv2.4.9 whith visual studio 2010
when I have to show an image program display the empty window and not show image

[image: this picture shows the problem]

and its my code:

```
#include<opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include<opencv\cv.h>

int main(int argc,char**argv[]) {
   IplImage* img1=cvLoadImage("C:\opencv\sources\samples\cpp\board.jpg");
  cvNamedWindow("img1",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
   cvShowImage("img1",img1);
   cvWaitKey(0);
   cvReleaseImage(&img1);
}
```

Comment: How come it didn't crash? You need to escape the \ s.

Comment: use  waitKey(100);

Comment: Don't use the old C API.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the way you wrote the path of the image. you should not use the escape character alone. You can solve it by one of these:

```
IplImage* img1=cvLoadImage("C:\\opencv\\sources\\samples\\cpp\\board.jpg");
```

Or:

```
IplImage* img1=cvLoadImage("C:/opencv/sources/samples/cpp/board.jpg");
```

Or:

```
IplImage* img1=cvLoadImage(R"(C:\opencv\sources\samples\cpp\board.jpg)");
```

BTW, you are using C interface which is really too out of data. If you do not have a REAL reason to use it, please do not. The equivalent code that use C++ is:

```
int main(int argc,char**argv[]) {
   cv::Mat img1=cv::imread("C:\\opencv\\sources\\samples\\cpp\\board.jpg");
   cv::namedWindow("img1",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
   cv::imshow("img1",img1);
   cv::waitKey(0);
   //No need to release manually 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use Mat then you can use:

```
       if (frame1.empty())

       {

            std::cout << "no image";

            break;

        }
```

then if the image not empty you should use more delay to display the images.
for example you can use:

```
 waitKey(100);
```